# How to implement Facebook's new emoting emojis: Love, haha, wow, sad and angry in android?

Tags: android, animation, facebook-like

I need to implement my own Facebook reaction popup in my app. While searching i came across with the below github app https://github.com/chRyNaN/Reactions. I have tried to called the Show method in  ReactionView class using below set of codes.

```
ReactionView reactionView =  new ReactionView(MainActivity.this);
        final Button mReactionView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
        mReactionView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {              
                reactionView.show(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But Reaction Popup is not visible. I am not sure, what i am missing? Can anybody help me on this?

Note: Github source is missing with layout folder and also Main activity class.

Answer (score 0):

It can be launched like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ReactionView reactionView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        reactionView = (ReactionView) findViewById(R.id.reaction);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                reactionView.show(motionEvent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="me.superup.reactions.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <me.superup.reactions.reactions.ReactionView
        android:id="@+id/reaction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add what i have add in the gradle here dependencies { ... }

Comment: @NourEldienMohamed there's no dependency, ReactionView class was taken from the repository above

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in build.gradle file...

```
implementation 'com.github.abbyChandra16:FB-Reaction:1.0'
```

Add a button in xml file and Inside activity.java file, add this code...

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(view -> 
    {
        Reaction var = new Reaction();
        var.react(this,view);

    });
```